# Why do these two radio buttons show up in Selenium with radically different targets(or locations on the page)?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

I have a form for Gender, and the first button is shown as below

```
name=radio_43
```

While the second button is shown like this:

```
xpath=(//input[@name='radio_43'])[2]
```

Why is the firm button called `radio_43` , then for the second it's using xpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your radio buttons have the name 'radio_43'. In order to differentiate between them, Selenium needs to call the second by its xpath. The direct selector `name=radio_43` will only pull the first one.

Comment: Ah I see, ok so it has to call the second by its xpath because they both have the name 'radio_43' cool, thanks so much!